# How does one physically measure geodesic deviation?

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

From wiki:

> one begins by setting up a family of closely spaced geodesics indexed
> by a continuous variable $s$ and parametrized by an affine parameter
> $\tau$. That is, for each fixed $s$, the curve swept out by
> $\gamma_s(\tau)$ as $\tau$ varies is a geodesic. When considering the
> geodesic of a massive object, it is often convenient to choose $\tau$
> to be the object's proper time. If $x_\mu(s, \tau)$ are the
> coordinates of the geodesic $\gamma_s(\tau)$, then the tangent vector
> of this geodesic is:

$$ T^\mu = \frac{\partial x^\mu(s,\tau)}{\partial \tau} $$

Can or how does one physically measure [geodesic deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation#:%7E:text=One%20can%20also%20define%20a,advance%20along%20their%20respective%20geodesics.)?

For example if I am undergoing geodesic motion and see a mirror undergoing motion and shoot a light beam at it. I measure the distance (metric) between the mirror and me and not the deviation vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I am not an expert in GR, but according to [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07173.pdf) paper, you could e.g. take two satellites orbiting earth which have systems for relative distance measurements built in. You then compare their measurement results to predictions for geodesic deviation in a Schwarzschild background that models earth.